# images to np array and keep the order

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I am trying to take 1967 jpg images to a np array with following codes.  How do I keep the original order of the images in the array?

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

X_data = []
files = glob.glob ("/content/drive/My Drive/CourseWork/images/emotionet_validation/*.jpg")
for myFile in files:
    print(myFile)
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    X_data.append (image)

print('X_data shape:', np.array(X_data).shape)
```

Comment: Indent your code 4 spaces to make it readable on S.O.

Comment: sort your `files` as you wish. `glob` doesn't guarantee any particular order...

Comment: What original order do you mean?

Comment: You probably want natsort library BTW.

Comment: When you save the image arrays from the list `X_data` to a NumPy array, they will be saved in the same order as they were read. If you want know the read order of the image files, you need another variable, maybe `img_label=[] ; img_label.append(myFile)`.

Comment: What original order do you mean? – Mad Physicist   =   how they were in the main folder ( i need the array sorted by image name XXXX5.jpg,   XXXXX8.jpg  etc)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

X_data = []
files = glob.glob ("/content/drive/My Drive/CourseWork/images/emotionet_validation/*.jpg")
sorted(files)
## Do you need sort to ignore case?
## sorted(files, key=str.casefold)
for myFile in files:
    print(myFile)
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    X_data.append (image)

print('X_data shape:', np.array(X_data).shape)
```